# HTTP headers not returned on EC2

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, http-headers, kotlin

I have a Spring Boot application deployed on 2 EC2 instances (staging and production environments). I have an endpoint that is used for downloading a file. It looks like this (the app is written in Kotlin):

```
@PostMapping("/download")
open fun download(@RequestBody request: DownloadRequest, servletResponse: HttpServletResponse) {
    val file = getByteArray(request.fileId)
    servletResponse.outputStream.write(file)
    servletResponse.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
    servletResponse.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"${request.fileId}.zip\"")
}
```

When I execute a download request on the staging machine everything is fine. I get back the file and the response has the headers set. These are the headers that I can see in Postman:

```
Cache-Control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Disposition →attachment; filename="345412.zip"
Content-Length →11756
Content-Type →application/octet-stream
Date →Tue, 04 Apr 2017 09:04:19 GMT
Expires →0
Pragma →no-cache
X-Application-Context →application:8081
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-Frame-Options →DENY
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
```

When I do the same request on production, the response body contains the file content, but the 2 headers that I set manually, "Content-Type" and "Content-Disposition", are missing:

```
Cache-Control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →56665
Date →Tue, 04 Apr 2017 09:06:45 GMT
Expires →0
Pragma →no-cache
X-Application-Context →application:8081
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-Frame-Options →DENY
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
```

Both machines have the exact same JAR deployed in a Docker container. Both calls are done directly against the EC2 instances, using their private IPs, so no ELB is involved. The configuration of the 2 instances is identical, with no differences that I could find in the AWS Console.

Do you know what might cause this? Is there a setting in EC2 that can prevent some HTTP headers for being sent back in responses? I cannot find any reason for why the headers are sent back in one case and not in the other.

Comment: I'm wondering if your request is actually hitting the `download` method. What is the HTTP code you get back from server when performing calling your prod host?

Comment: @Trein The status code is 200 both for staging and production. How could my request not reach the `download` method? I am getting back the file contents in the response body.

Comment: You're right. I missed the part where you said the response body comes back with file contents. Is there any environment variable being set differently in one of the two environments? Spring Boot has several built-in levers and switches that can be causing staging/prod differences.

Comment: @Trein The only Spring-related configuration difference between the two environments are the DB config properties (spring.datasource.url, username and password). I am using default values for the rest on both environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by first writing the response headers and then the response body:

```
@PostMapping("/download")
open fun download(@RequestBody request: DownloadRequest, servletResponse: HttpServletResponse) {
    val file = getByteArray(request.fileId)
    servletResponse.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
    servletResponse.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"${request.fileId}.zip\"")
    servletResponse.outputStream.write(file)
}
```

If you start writing the body first, the headers might not be properly set. I am still not sure why this was reproducing only on the production machine.